# Increment date in shell script on AIX

Tags: perl, shell, date, sh, ksh

I have to create a shell script file that accepts a string, start date and end date and generates the output file in the below format.

Note : Dates are in MM/DD/YYYY

```
string,start date
string,start date + 1
...
string,end date
```

I am not able to increment the date. I tried using `date -d` option but it is not available on AIX.

Could someone please help with a built in shell script command or perl command to increment the date ?.

Comment: Can you install 3rd-party perl modules, or do you need to stick with built-in functionality? If the latter, exactly which version of Perl do you have? (Also, do you have a Python interpreter? If so, again, exactly which version?)

Comment: ...aside: `MM/DD/YYYY` is perhaps the worst widely-used date format (other than `MON/DD/YY`): ASCII sort treats it badly, and it's often ambiguous (one often can't tell if you're using `DD/MM/YYYY`, which is also popular). When you have control, `YYYY-MM-DD` is the Right Thing: It's much less ambiguous to human readers, it's RFC-compliant, and it sorts nicely.

Comment: "`MM/DD/YYYY` is perhaps the worst widely-used date format" Not to mention that it doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Hi, I do not have built in modules.  I found the below command to increment the system date 'perl -e 'use POSIX;print strftime "%Y-%m-%d",localtime time+86400'. I am looking for a perl command that accepts  a date and increments it.

Comment: If you don't have built-in modules, you don't have Perl.  Perl is the interpreter, and the modules that ship with the interpreter, and its POD (documentation).

Comment: I get this error Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC

Comment: DateTime isn't a built-in module.  See the FAQ: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-find-yesterday%27s-date%3f  ...the principles expressed there would apply to your question of "how do I find tomorrow's date?" Pay specific attention to Time::Piece and Time::Seconds, since they DO ship with Perl.

Comment: My question about whether you have a Python interpreter remains unanswered. (Someone else might give you a Perl answer; I could certainly give you a Python one, wrapped in a shell function if that makes it easier).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, ...I'm not sure that it is, inasmuch as this one has a "built-in modules only" restriction, thus excluding DateTime, whereas the other question has no such restriction.

Answer (score 2):

Given a constraint of 'uses core':

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y';

my $start = '01/22/2016';
my $end   = '01/31/2016';

my $start_t = Time::Piece->strptime( $start, $FORMAT );
my $end_t   = Time::Piece->strptime( $end,   $FORMAT );

while ( $start_t <= $end_t ) {
   print $start_t ->strftime($FORMAT), "\n";
   $start_t += ONE_DAY;
}
```

Both `Time::Piece` and `Time::Seconds` are core as of perl 5.9.5. The latter is only needed for `ONE_DAY` - otherwise you can just add `60 * 60 * 24` instead.

I'm sure you can figure out how to print the strings etc. yourself.

(I'd also note - this is a horrible time format, and [should be avoided](https://xkcd.com/1179/))

Comment: Love the ISO 8601 link - how true!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a shellscript using awk like this:

```
str="some string"
startd="12/25/2016"
endd="1/17/2017"

maxloop=10

echo "${maxloop}" |
awk -v string="${str}" -v startdate="${startd}" -v enddate="${endd}" '{
    split(startdate,A,"[/]");
    T1=mktime(A[3] " " A[1] " " A[2] " 0 0 0");
    split(enddate,B,"[/]");
    T2=mktime(B[3] " " B[1] " " B[2] " 23 59 59");
    linenr=1;
    while (T1 < T2) {
       printf("%s,%s\n",string,
          strftime("%m-%d-%Y",T1));
       T1+=3600*24;
       if (linenr++ > $1) break;
    }
}'
```

The linenr/maxloop is not adding something to the solution but will help against
mistakes in the input values or maintenance of the script.